# Prove that if $x, y ∈$ B̅$(z,r)$ such that $||x - y|| ≥ εr$, then $||z - {{x+y} \over 2}|| ≤ r \sqrt{1 - {{ε^2} \over 4}}$.

Tags: analysis

Let $z ∈ ℝ^n$, $r > 0$, and $ε ∈ (0, 2]$. Prove that if $x, y ∈$ B̅$(z,r)$ such that $||x - y|| ≥ εr$, then $||z - {{x+y} \over 2}|| ≤ r \sqrt{1 - {{ε^2} \over 4}}$.

> my take on this exercise (not much, but I tried):

Knowing that B̅$(z,r)$ is a closed ball, we can say:

$||x-z|| ≤ r$ and $||y-z|| ≤ r$

From the triangle inequality we also know:

$| ||x|| - ||y|| ≤ ||x-y||$

How to continue to get the conclusion?

Comment: Here $||.||$ is the Euclidean norm ?

Comment: This is literally the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3925332/if-x-y-in-overlinebz-r-such-that-x-y-ge-epsilon-r-then-z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\alpha=z-x$, $\beta=z-y$ and $\gamma=y-x=\alpha-\beta$, where
$$|\alpha|^2,|\beta|^2\leq r^2,\qquad |\gamma|^2\geq \varepsilon^2 r^2.$$
We only need to prove
$$(\alpha+\beta,\alpha+\beta)\leq r^2(4-\varepsilon^2).$$
Note that
$$\begin{aligned}
(\alpha+\beta,\alpha+\beta)&=|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2+2(\alpha,\beta),\\
\varepsilon^2 r^2\leq |\gamma|^2=(\alpha-\beta,\alpha-\beta)&=|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2-2(\alpha,\beta).
\end{aligned}$$
It follows that
$$\begin{aligned}
|\alpha+\beta|^2&\leq 2(|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2)-\varepsilon^2 r^2\\
&\leq (4-\varepsilon^2)r^2.
\end{aligned}$$